# Page Redirection Not Working Properly when Web application is deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, client

I have two web applications which communicate between them. I have tested both applications on the Cassini server and they work as they should.

I then deployed both applications as SSL on IIS. One of the applications works perfectly. The other application works also. However, at one point, this application makes a web service request to the other application, which returns a URL to the requesting application. The requesting application then redirects the user to that URL.

Unfortunately, the redirect is not working in the sense that it remains "connecting" but nothing loads up. What is the root cause of this? Is it because they don't have valid certificates? Did someone else experience this problem? How can I solve it?

This is how I am passing the URL in a JObject from the web service:

```
obj["URL"] = "https://localhost:2001/CheckOut.aspx?GUID=" + guid;
```

This is how I am loading the URL at the "client" (the application making the request):

```
string script_value = "window.open('CheckOutConfirmation.aspx', '_newtab');";
script_value += "window.location.href = '" + response_object.URL + "';";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, script_value, true);
```

I want to clarify that this code worked correctly when not on IIS.  When I deployed it to IIS, I changed the URL to reflect the new address and port.  I made sure that the URL is working by pasting it in the address bar from the project.  Moreover, the web service call is being made as the address bar displays `"localhost:2001/CheckOut.aspx?GUID=etc etc etc"`.  However, it stays "connecting" until a timeout occurs.

**Update**

If I add https:// before the address displayed in the URL, it works.  Why is the requesting application loading the address as "localhost:2001/CheckOut.aspx?GUID=etc etc etc" when in reality I passed "`https://localhost:2001/CheckOut.aspx?GUID=" + guid;?`